# Creating Java Object with reserved keywords as variable name

Tags: java, json

I have JSON that needs to be converted to a Java Object. The JSONs I need to handle can look like this:

```
{
    "documents": [
        {
        "title": "Jobs",
        "is-saved": false,
        "abstract": "<span class=\"hit\">Jobs</span> may refer to:\n\n* Steve <span class=\"hit\">Jobs</span> (1955–2011), co-founder and former CEO of consumer electronics company...<br />",
        "id": "Jobs",
        "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jobs"
        }
    ],

   "keywords_local": [
       {
        "keyword": "Jobs",
        "interest": 1,
        "angle": 0
       }
   ],
   "sessionid": "6cd6402e-1f67-45a8-b0fa-e79a5d0d50f4",
   "q": "Jobs",
}
```

This JSON is returned when entering a search keyword on a searchengine, in this case "Jobs". I have not named these variables-to-be-created, this JSON was just "given" to me from a similar earlier app. So I'm obviously having trouble with variables is-saved and abstract. Abstract is a reserved keyword and everywhere I read a reserved keyword CANNOT be used as a variable name.

I do not have access to the previous app that I am sort of updating and I guess the point to that is that I need to figure it out by myself ;) But I am a bit of a stand still now, have no idea of how to move forward.

I'm a newbie, so do not give me hell if I'm asking a stupid question, it's my first time coding any sort of app! ;)
Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you attempting to serialise the object of read the data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use GSON for parsing you can name your members as you want and annotate them for mapping.

```
@SerializedName("abstract")
private String abstractText;
```

Answer (score 12):

Another option you've got is to use Jackson, and use the `@JsonProperty` annotation..

```
@JsonProperty("abstract")
private String abstractText;
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea I could use this, this will work great for me!

Comment: As much as I enjoy the approval, could you please accept the first answer given by Christoph? He laid out the concept. I just supplemented the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @christopher. You shouldn't have!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it depends on the tool you are using. With tools mapping directly to your custom POJO  (like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md), [Jackson](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-introduction.jsp)), you need to map your JSON field name with your Java correct and valid field name.

If you use a mors basic library such as [JSON.org](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)'s, there is no need to do so because you parse it to specific object allowing you to handle it.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("documents");
String abstractValue = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("abstract");
```