# Problem with getter and setter with variable name same as a function

Tags: java, android

I parse a JSON file (with Gson) with getters and setters. All works correctly. But in my JSON I have a variable named "switch". If I include this name in my class like that

private String switch;

This does not work because switch is a function of Java but I have to get with this name exactly if I want my parsing works.

Want I can do?

Thanks

Sorry I'm very noob with Java, I'm still learning.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653584/creating-java-object-with-reserved-keywords-as-variable-name

Answer (score 4):

It's possible by using GSON's [Field Naming Support](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support)

```java
@SerializedName("switch")
private String Switch;
public String getSwitch ()
{
    return Switch;
}
public void setSwitch (String aSwitch)
{
    Switch= aSwitch;
}
```

Comment: Yeah no problem, well you can also go for ```@JsonProperty```